# Compute a proof for a verifiable delay function

Tags: rsa, public-key, prime-numbers

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Alice generates a RSA key $(n, \phi)$, she shares with Bob the value $n$, and $y = g^{2^{t}}\;\text{mod}\; n$ for $g$ a generator of the group $\left(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\right)^{*}$ and $t$ a very large number for example $2^{512}$. She then asks Bob for an input $z$ ($\neq y$) and sends him a relatively small random prime (challenge) $\ell$ and $\pi$ a proof of $y$ such that $$\pi = g^{\left\lfloor\frac{2^t}{\ell}\right\rfloor}\;\text{mod}\; n$$ and so $$y = \pi^{\ell} g^r\; \text{mod} \; n$$ where $r = 2^t \; \text{mod}\; \ell$. Now Bob needs to find a proof $\psi$ for $z$ such that: $$z = \psi^{\ell} g^r\; \text{mod} \; n.$$

It is clear that if Bob has an access to $\phi$ he can find $d = \ell^{-1}\;\text{mod}\; \phi$ and solve the problem by chosing $\psi = \left(z g^r\right)^d \;\text{mod}\; n$. However in my case $n$ is large that it is almost impossible for me to compute the prime factorization of $n$ to find $\phi$. Can any one help me to find an idea of how to find $\psi$?

Comment: Shall we read "$2^t$ a very large number for example $2^{512}$" where there is "$t$ a very large number for example $2^{512}$"? If not: for $n$ the product of two distinct primes $p$ and $q$, in order to compute $y=g^{(2^{(2^{512})})}\bmod n$, it looks like Alice must be able to factor $p-1$ and $q-1$, which is not a standard assumption in RSA. And uh, I have not yet found how Alice would computes $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For computing $y$ Alice knows the private keys $p$ and $q$ or at least the value of $\phi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it. Indeed, Bob can send $z = -y \;\text{mod} \; n$ and then $\psi$ will be simply $-\pi \; \text{mod}\; n$.